# How to switch src and onclick with previous and next buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello im working on a game fan guide page but now I will not go any further and search for help.

I need a way to get the next or/and previous img on click a previous arrow and next arrow.

All this is new for me and i have test many but nothing have work, i hope anyone can help me out.

now i have see my html have make issus but i have fix and now i can post my html.

I have the CSS style and HTML for a better view split but in my html it is alle in one and a meta for viewport.

edit: sry, but i have make thinking errors. it is not enough to change the pic i have to change the wohle div content.

explane on click next have to change div id="card1" class="card_content" to div id="card2" class="card_content"

```css
a img {
  border:none;
}

.card_overlay {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 1001;
}

.card_content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  height:600px;
  width:305px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -258px;
  margin-left: -156px;
  padding: 6px;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 1002;
  overflow: auto;
}

#card_icons {
  width:299px;
  border:0;
}

.card_case {
  background-image: url(http://file2.npage.de/014720/85/bilder/case.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height:435px;
  width:299px;
  border:0;
}

.switch_card {
position:relative;
z-index:1003;
margin-top:-235px;
margin-left:-5px;
}

#back_to {
position:relative;
z-index:1003;
margin-top:203px;
margin-left:0px;
}
```

```html
 <table>
  <tr>
  <td>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('card1').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'"><img src="http://file2.npage.de/014720/85/bilder/grabwaechters_vasall.png" title="Grabwächters Vasall" /></a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('card2').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'"><img src="http://file2.npage.de/014720/85/bilder/des_kaenguru.png" title="Grabwächters Vasall" /></a>
  </td>
  </tr>
 </table>




 <div id="card1" class="card_content">
  <table id="card_icons">
   <tr>
    <td align="left" width="80"><img src="http://file2.npage.de/014720/85/bilder/stapel.png" height="17" width="24"><font color="white"> 1/20</font></td>
    <td align="left" width="60"><img src="http://file2.npage.de/014720/85/bilder/ex.png" height="17" width="14"><font color="white"> 0/ 2</font></td>
    <td align="right"><img src="http://file2.npage.de/014720/85/bilder/ur.png"></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="card_case">
   <tr>
    <td valign="middle" align="center"><img src="http://file2.npage.de/014720/85/bilder/big_grabwaechters_vasall.png"></td>
   </tr>
  </table>

     <div class="switch_card">
      <table width="100%"  border="0"  cellpadding="0"  cellspacing="0">
       <tr>
        <td align="left"><a href="previous card"><img src="http://file2.npage.de/014720/85/bilder/links2.png"></a></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right"><a href="next card"><img src="http://file2.npage.de/014720/85/bilder/rechts2.png"></a></td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </div>

  <div id="back_to"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('card1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'" unselectable="off"><img src="http://file2.npage.de/014720/85/bilder/back.png" title="zurück"  /></a></div>
 </div>

 <div id="card2" class="card_content">
  <table id="card_icons">
   <tr>
    <td align="left" width="80"><img src="http://file2.npage.de/014720/85/bilder/stapel.png" height="17" width="24"><font color="white"> 1/20</font></td>
    <td align="left" width="60"><img src="http://file2.npage.de/014720/85/bilder/ex.png" height="17" width="14"><font color="white"> 0/ 2</font></td>
    <td align="right"><img src="http://file2.npage.de/014720/85/bilder/ur.png"></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="card_case">
   <tr>
    <td valign="middle" align="center"><img src="http://file2.npage.de/014720/85/bilder/big_des_kaenguru.png">
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>

     <div class="switch_card">
      <table width="100%"  border="0"  cellpadding="0"  cellspacing="0">
       <tr>
        <td align="left"><a href="previous card"><img src="http://file2.npage.de/014720/85/bilder/links2.png"></a></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right"><a href="next card"><img src="http://file2.npage.de/014720/85/bilder/rechts2.png"></a></td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </div>

  <div id="back_to"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('card2').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'" unselectable="off"><img src="http://file2.npage.de/014720/85/bilder/back.png" title="zurück"  /></a></div>
 </div>


 <div id="fade" class="card_overlay"></div>
```

Comment: Can you at least provide a sample code and state what you are trying to achieve? This way, you will get a more precise answer.

Comment: ok now i have post css and html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below may help you.

```
// index.html
<img src="01.png" id="pic">

// script.js
document.getElementById("pic").setAttribute("src", "02.png")
```

Comment: thx, but i have make thinking errors. it is not enough to change the pic I have to change the wohle div content.

Answer (score 0):

Got it done with

```css
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('card1').style.display='non‌​e';document.getEleme‌​ntById('fade').style‌​.display='none';docu‌​ment.getElementById(‌​'card2').style.displ‌​ay='block';document.‌​getElementById('fade‌​').style.display='bl‌​ock'" unselectable="off">
```

But how do i make the javascript: void with a script.js